# How do I set the text of a custom cell's textfield to a variable inside a custom object array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table view with custom cells, and each cell has a text field. I want to take the text in the textfield and put it inside my [classes] : [ClassObject].title for each cell. The problem is that it won't work!

**Here's the code**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCell")! as! EditCell
    let c = classes[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleTF.text = c.title
    c.title = cell.titleTF.text

    return cell
}
```

**And heres the custom class object**

```
class ClassObject: NSObject, NSCoding {

var title : String?
var detail : String?
var startTime : String?
var endTime: String?
var stuff : [String]?
var info : String?
var titleColor : UIColor?


enum state {
    case normal,red,yellow
}

func setStates(currentState : state) {
    switch currentState {
    case .normal:
        titleColor = UIColor.black
    case .red:
        titleColor = UIColor.red
    case .yellow:
        titleColor = UIColor(red: 203/255, green: 154/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

init(title: String, detail: String, startTime: String, endTime: String, stuff: Array<String>, info: String, titleColor: UIColor) {
    self.title = title
    self.detail = detail
    self.startTime = startTime
    self.endTime = endTime
    self.stuff = stuff
    self.info = info
    self.titleColor = titleColor

}


required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title")
    let detail = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "detail")
    let startTime = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "startTime")
    let endTime = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "endTime")
    let stuff = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "stuff")
    let info = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "info")
    let titleColor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "titleColor")
    self.init(title: title as! String, detail: detail as! String, startTime: startTime as! String, endTime: endTime as! String, stuff: stuff as! Array<String>, info: info as! String, titleColor: titleColor as! UIColor)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
    aCoder.encode(detail, forKey: "detail")
    aCoder.encode(startTime, forKey: "startTime")
    aCoder.encode(endTime, forKey: "endTime")
    aCoder.encode(stuff, forKey: "stuff")
    aCoder.encode(info, forKey: "info")
    aCoder.encode(titleColor, forKey: "titleColor")
}
override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

}

**At last heres the custom UITableViewCell**

```
class EditCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet weak var titleTF: UITextField!




override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: Where's your attempt to update your data model with the text entered into one of the text fields?

Comment: @rmaddy Oh i just removed that but i have tried it. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Can you add you custom object code?

Comment: So I've updated the question and added the Custom object class and the custom cell class @BenjaminLowry

Comment: Thank you! What is not working exactly? I can only assume that you want to populate the `UITableViewCell` `UITextField` with `ClassObject.title`, as taken from an array, right? If so, have you verified that (1) the classes[] is properly populated and (2) the text field is setup properly?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect The thing i want to do is: I want to take the text out of the cell.titleTF and but it into the classes[indexpath.row].title when I click "Save" (a bar button item). I hope I was clear enough

Comment: Then you cannot possibly do it like this: as I stated in my response, the cells are transient, UI elements. They also are reused. In other words, only the visible cells exist, if at all, and are recycled to display data. You cannot cycle through the to get back to the data. You must store the user changes _on the fly_ back into your model (or a copy of it), and positively do not rely on the view to store user data for you. This is the basis of MVC design: the **model** _is_ the data,

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

#### Prerequisites

1. Is `EditCell` properly setup? i.e. can it display, say, a debug string:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                           cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
                                                "newCell")! as! EditCell
       cell.titleTF.text = "debug row \(indexPath.row)"
       return cell
   }
   ```
2. Is your model properly setup? i.e. can you log its content:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                           cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
                                                "newCell")! as! EditCell
       let c = classes[indexPath.row]
       print("c.title at index \(indexPath.row): \(c.title)")
       cell.titleTF.text = c.title
       return cell
   }
   ```

---

#### Discussion

Assuming that you have an `EditCell` looking like this:

```
class EditCell : UITableViewCell {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    var titleTF:UILabel
}
```

and a structure `aClass` defined more or less like that:

```
struct aClass {
    var title:String
}
```

and lastly an array of such `aClass` defined like so:

```
var classes:[aClass] = [aClass.init(title: "demo")]
```

*then* the code below cannot possibly compile unless you comment out `c.title = ...`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCell")! as! EditCell
    let c = classes[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleTF.text = c.title
    ///c.title = cell.titleTF.text
    return cell
}
```

which leads to this analysis ; if you actually want to take the content of the cell and put it back into an array, as this sentence seems to imply:

> I want to take the text in the textfield and put it inside my [classes] : [ClassObject].title for each cell.

the place to do so is not in `dequeueReusableCell` which is exactly the opposite. The only time to change your model is when the cell is changed, as cells are transient and reused, not persisting any data.

---

#### Conclusion

*from comment*

User Interface cells are transient, UI elements. They also are reused.
In other words, only the visible cells exist, if at all, and are recycled to display data.

You cannot cycle through the to get back to the data. You must store the user changes on the fly back into your model (or a copy of it), and positively do not rely on the view to store user data for you. This is the basis of MVC design: the model is the data.

The action of **saving** is the equivalent of committing the new model.

Hint: *If you use `NSFetchedResultsController`, a lot of this boilerplate work is done by the OS.*

Comment: Where should i but it then?

Comment: So I've updated the question and added the Custom object class and the custom cell class

Comment: Great. I've added some hints (and will remove this comment eventually)